# Adding white noise to a signal of two variables

Tags: image-processing, signal-processing, random-process

When a signal depends on two variables, e.g.,

```
f[k1_, k2_] := 
  Exp[I 0.75 (k1 + 0.3 k2)] + 1.5 Exp[I (0.2 k1 + 0.3 k2)] + Exp[I (0.2 k1 + 0.4 k2)];
```

where `k1, k2` are integers.

1. How can I add or simulate white noise here?
2. How can I do this just for integers?

In the documentation, I found that to add withe noise to a signal one should do the following:

```
TransformedProcess[
    Cos[t/8] + noise[t], 
    noise \[Distributed] WhiteNoiseProcess[UniformDistribution[{-1/5, 1/5}]],
    t];
```

But I can't make it work with my function `f`.

Comment: Anna, not seeing a process with your `f[k1,k2]`. Where does `t` fit in?

Comment: In general, white noise just means there is no correlation between each instant in time, so easy to generate it. Just need some more info from you on your problem.

Comment: Does f[k1_, k2_] := Exp[I*(k1*0.75 + 0.3*k2)] + 1.5*Exp[I*(k1*0.2 + 0.3*k2)] + 
  Exp[I*(k1*0.7 + 0.4*k2)] + RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[]] do what you are looking for?

Comment: Specifically, we need to know if you are trying to add noise to the function f[k1,k2] or to a random choice of k1 and k2.

Comment: For calculations I need to use just discrete samples of `f[k1,k2]` , and they do not depend on time, therefore I don't know jet, how I should do white noise simulation properly..., and if just adding `RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[]]`  is correct in this case. @AnnaVeselovska

Comment: @MikeY For calculations I need to use just discrete samples of 'f[k1,k2]' , and they do not depend on time, therefore I don't know jet, how I should do white noise simulation properly..., and if just adding 'RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[]]' is correct in this case.

Answer (score 2):

I have a quick and dirty white noise function I use sometimes:

```
whitenoise[d_, t_] := d RandomReal[{-1, 1}]/Sqrt[t]
```

d being the delta, the larger d is, the larger your noise 'amplitude' will become, as can be seen in the following image, and t is your discrete delta t.

In this case, whitenoise is additive, and can be simply added to your signal.

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[{Sin[t 5]/2.5 + whitenoise[b, 0.1]}, {t, 0, \[Pi]/4}, 
  ImageSize -> Large], {b, 0.001, 1}]
```

As you can see it can turn a Sin[t] pretty noisy. Click the image if it doesn't animate.
[image: noisy]

This also works quite well on making noisy real numbers for your variables.

Taking your function and making some data and plotting:

```
data1 = Table[{Re[f[i, i + 0.1]], Im[f[i, i + 0.1]]}, {i, 0, 5000}];
datanoisy = Table[{Re[f[i, i + 0.1]] + whitenoise[0.01, 0.1], 
    Im[f[i, i + 0.1]] + whitenoise[0.01, 0.1]}, {i, 0, 5000}];

ListPlot[{data1, datanoisy}]
```

[image: plot2]

It looks like some kind of pattern is emerging....

Interesting!

[image: other]

Hope this is helpful!